# ¿Cómo ordenar los índices de salida en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

El programa consiste en contar la cantidad de palabras repetidas de una cadena, entonces en el main creo una matriz con las palabras y las paso al método *insertarPalabra* en la clase *Coleccion2* donde las almaceno en un `ArrayList<>` *coleccion* ya que no sé cuántas palabras van a llegar del main. A su vez tengo otro `ArrayList<>` *contador* para almacenar las veces que se repite la palabra, pero a la hora de imprimirlo en pantalla no me sale los valores en orden ya que no logro borrar del Array la posición adecuada. (El programa ya lo había realizado con matrices).

```
public class ContadorVer2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Digite una cadena");
        String leer = Leer.dato();
        String[] cole = leer.split(" ");
        
        Coleccion2 pal = new Coleccion2();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cole.length; i++) {
          pal.insertarPalabra(cole[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Cantidad de palabras: ");
        pal.Visualizar();
   }  
}

public class Coleccion2 {
     
     ArrayList<Integer> contador = new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayList<String> coleccion = new ArrayList<>();        
     
     public void insertarPalabra(String pala) {     
    
        int cantidad = 1;
     
         for (int i = 0; i < coleccion.size(); i++) {
             if (coleccion.get(i).equals(pala)) {
                 coleccion.remove(pala);
                 contador.remove(i);
                 contador.add(i, cantidad +1);
             }                       
         }
         coleccion.add(pala);
         contador.add(cantidad);
     }
     
     public void Visualizar() {
         for(int i=0; i < coleccion.size(); i++) {
             System.out.print(coleccion.get(i) +" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
         for(int e: contador){
             System.out.print(e+" ");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `HashMap` que es una diccionarios <clave,valor> donde la clave es única. En tu caso la palabra sería la clave y el valor la cantidad de ocurrencias.

El `HashMap` tiene una función `put` para ingresar una nueva entrada si esta no existe, y si la clave existe actualiza su valor (insert or update)

Además está la función `getOrDefault(clave, valor_por_default)` que retorna el valor según la clave, y si no existe retorna el valor por default.

```
public class Coleccion2 {
    HashMap<String,Integer> palabras = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

     public void insertarPalabra(String pala){
         palabras.put(pala, palabras.getOrDefault(pala, 0) + 1);
     }
     
     public void Visualizar(){
         for (String k : palabras.keySet()) {
             System.out.println(k + " : " + palabras.get(k));
         }            
     }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo de esta manera!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void insertarPalabra( String pala ) {     
    
    int cantidad = 0;
 
     for (int i = 0; i < coleccion.size(); i++) {
         if (coleccion.get(i).equals(pala)) {

               // si quitamos la palabra de la lista, "estamos al horno"
               // así que la siguiente linea desaparece.
           //  coleccion.remove(pala);

             // antes de "tocar" contador(i), almacenamos su valor que 
             // puede ser uno, diez... 
             cantidad = cantidades.get( i );

             // cambiamos la forma de modificar contador, en vez de 
             // eliminar la entrada, la actualizamos con el método "set"
             // otra linea que desaparece...
        //     contador.remove(i);
             contador.set( i, cantidad +1 );
 
      // fundamental hacer un return para no llegar a colección.add() y
      // contador.add(), ya que nos daría valores incorrectos
             return;
         }                       
     }
     coleccion.add(pala);
     contador.add(cantidad);
 }
```

Para el método visualizar, tenes dos opciones:

```
 public void Visualizar() {
     for( int i=0; i < coleccion.size(); i++ ) {
         System.out.println( coleccion.get(i) + " hay " + contador.get( i ));
     }
 }
```

Super sencilla, imprime la palabra y cuantas veces se repite, en la misma linea.

```
public void Visualizar() {
   for( int i = 0; i < coleccion.size(); i++ ) {
      System.out.print( coleccion.get( i ) + " " );
   }
   System.out.println();
   for( int e : contador ) {
      System.out.print( e + "     " );
   }
}
```

Esta es la que creaste, pero depende del tamaño de las palabras encontradas, que te queden acomodados los valores.

Comment: He aprendido mucho con esta correción pero aún tengo una duda, que retorna el return dentro del ciclo?

Comment: Hola Victor, si te fijas, el método está declarado como **void**, osea que no retorna nada, solo se usa para salir del método, es parecido a cuando usas un **break** para salir de un bucle.

Comment: Ahh ok y solo funciona en métodos void?. De antemano, gracias!!

Comment: Si el método no es **void**, por ejemplo **public String buscarPalabra() {**, obligatoriamente tiene que tener un **return**, y tiene que devolver un **String** (o cualquier otra cosa que se declare), la declaración Del método la podrías ver como un contrato, prometo lo que voy a devolver.